# Как сделать массив из ref в react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Есть задача, по нажатию на кнопку скролл прокручивается до определенного блока.
Создал ref и функцию на наведение на блок, у которого есть ref:

```
const myRef = React.useRef(null);

const executeScroll = () => (myRef.current.scrollIntoView());

.........

<div onClick={() => executeScroll()} className={styles.contentChapter}></div>

.........

<div ref={myRef} className={styles.chapter}><b>123</b></div>
```

А если будет несколько блоков, как для каждого ref'a, сделать это в виде массива?

```
<div ref={myRef} className={styles.chapter}><b>123</b></div>
<div ref={myRef} className={styles.chapter}><b>234</b></div>
<div ref={myRef} className={styles.chapter}><b>345</b></div>
```

Comment: у каждого отдельного элемента свой ref, поэтому использование массива вполне логично.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Помогли с решением, если кому понадобится, оставлю тут)

```
const refArray = useRef<HTMLDivElement[]>([]);
const addToRefs = useCallback((el: HTMLDivElement | null, index: number) => {
     if (!el || refArray.current.includes(el)) return;
     refArray.current.splice(index, 0, el);
}, []);

...

// Then use the array index with the scroll handler function
const executeScroll = (index :number) => (refArray.current?. 
      [index]?.scrollIntoView());
...

return yourArray.map((d, index) => (
    <div
      key={d.id}
      ref={(ele) => {
      addToRefs(ele, index);
    }}
  >
  {d.yourProperty}
     </div>
    ));
```